# exp(a) goes to 0 and exp(a)exp(b) goes to infinity. What's a and b?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, infinity

Suppose it is given that

$e^{(a+b)} = e^a e^b \rightarrow \infty$

and that

$e^a \rightarrow 0$.

Is it possible to state mathematically how the values for $a$ and $b$ that fulfill this look like? Intuitively, $a$ should have to go to $-\infty$ while $b$ must go to $+\infty$, but ''faster'' if that is even a mathematical concept in that context.

Comment: You have these limits, but it's not clear what the variable is. Sure we have $e^{a + b} \to \infty$, but as what tends to what?

Comment: Presumably you want to couple $a$ and $b$ by making them functions of a third variable say $t$. Then $a(t)$ needs to go to $-\infty$, $b(t)$ needs to go to $+\infty$, and $b(t)$ needs to grow faster than $a(t)$ does, which you could express by saying $|b(t)/a(t)| \to \infty$ or by using little oh or Big Omega notation. This is all happening as $t$ goes to some limit (doesn't really matter where, you can parametrize things so the "endpoint" of the process is wherever you want).

Comment: The idea is that we know from $e^{a} \rightarrow 0$ that $a$ has to tend to minus infinity for that to hold. Given that $a$ tends to minus infinity, where has $b$ to tend such that $e^{a+b}$ tends to infinity? Is it valid to note that $a \rightarrow - \infty$, $b \rightarrow \infty$ and $\frac{a}{b} \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: $b=-a+c$ where $c$ goes to infinity. As for the previous question if you take $a=-b/2$ then $a/b$ goes to $-1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be functions of x.

Let $a(x)=-x$ and $b(x)=2x$

Then it is easy to see that $$e^a\rightarrow 0\ \ \  as\ \ \  x\rightarrow \infty\ \ \ or \ \ \ a\rightarrow -\infty$$and$$e^b\rightarrow \infty\ \ \  as\ \ \  x\rightarrow \infty\ \ \ or \ \ \ b\rightarrow \infty$$and$$e^{a+b}\rightarrow \infty\ \ \  as\ \ \  x\rightarrow \infty\ \ \ or \ \ \ b\rightarrow \infty\ \ \ \ \&\ \ \ a\rightarrow -\infty$$

Comment: Is the limit of $e^{a+b}$ defined if $b \rightarrow \infty$ and $a \rightarrow -\infty$?

Comment: @Mr.Zen The limit can exist, but you cannot replace $a$ and $b$ by their limiting values to infer what that limit is; we say $\infty - \infty$ is an indeterminate form. The limit can also just fail to exist outright, like if $b(x)=-a(x)+\sin(x)$.